# ARM: Is "STMDB SP!, {R0-R8}" (aka PUSH {R0-R8}) an atomic operation?

Tags: assembly, stack, arm, atomic

I wonder if STMDB SP!, {R0-R8} is an atomic operation in ARM(v7), because it looks quite complex to me. So is it for example possible, that the CPU is interrupted somewhere "in the middle" and has already stored R5-R8 on the stack and the SP is now SP_old - 16 and after handling the interrupt the processor continues with R0-R4? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

To clarify upon the slightly confusing mix of answers here, first up; v7-A<sup>1</sup>:

**In the standard configuration** the only exception that can interrupt a multiple access instruction is a synchronous data abort, so they are effectively atomic in terms of interrupts (though *not* in terms of memory accesses).

This is *not* true, however,  if the low-latency interrupt configuration is supported and has been enabled. Here IRQs, FIQs and asynchronous aborts can also interrupt the instruction. To quote the v7-A ARM ARM on this:

> ARM deprecates any software reliance on the behavior that an interrupt or asynchronous abort cannot occur in a sequence of memory transactions generated by a single load or store instruction that accesses Normal memory.
>
> **Note**
>
> A particular case that has shown this reliance is load multiples that load the stack pointer from memory. In an implementation where an interrupt is taken during the LDM, this can corrupt the stack pointer.

An instruction interrupted this way will be abandoned and, if returned to, execution restarted form the beginning (thus for stores the lower addresses may see two writes).

Secondly v7-M<sup>2</sup>, with its wacky exception model:

Here it's low-latency all day every day. Exceptions can always be taken during multiple access instructions, but the architecture allows (in certain conditions) for continuing execution from the point of interruption as per the suggestion in the question. Abandon-and-restart behaviour is also permitted as an alternative, and is the only option for non-continuable instruction/exception combinations.

[1] sections A3.5.3 and B1.8.12 of the [ARMv7-A ARM (DDI0406C.b)](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0406c/index.html)

[2] section B1.5.10 of the [ARMv7-M ARM (DDI0403D)](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0403c/index.html)

Answer (score 4):

It is atomic, as far as interrupt handling is concerned.

If I remember correctly, interrupting the instruction causes it to be aborted and re-executed after interrupt processing has finished, in order to guarantee interrupt latency.

Comment: I believe some of the VFP instructions are also interruptible in the same manner. They will abort and restart after returning from the interrupt.

Answer (score 2):

If configured, it can be interrupted then restarted (not continued). It can also be aborted if the memory is inaccessable.

It is not atomic with respect to other devices.

Comment: @artlessnoise Agreed, this says it all nice and succinctly - I only answered because it would have been too much for an edit, and to also cover V7-M just in case. References clarified.

Answer (score 1):

`STM` is a single instruction, so it is atomic as much as other instructions. You tell the cpu to save N registers starting from memory pointed by SP-4 then update SP to SP-N*4 in a single instruction. So it is its responsibility to keep things in a consistent state between different mode switches (aka interrupts).