# What happens if there's an IRQ when executing a stmfd instruction?

Tags: arm

Is the stmfd instruction seen as a single instruction, and so does it mean that it's going to be fully executed before dealing with the IRQ?
Or is it seen as multiple instructions and so does it mean that we're going to deal with the IRQ and finish the stmfd instruction after?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ARM: Is "STMDB SP!, {R0-R8}" (aka PUSH {R0-R8}) an atomic operation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628136/arm-is-stmdb-sp-r0-r8-aka-push-r0-r8-an-atomic-operation)

Comment: depends on the core, have to look at each one separately and/or the specific one you have.

Comment: you generally should not care what instruction was interrupted.  the only time you care is if this is talking to a (poorly designed) peripheral that acts on writes, in a way that if some of the writes happened and then stopped and then some of them happened again (at their same addresses) or it continues where it left off the perpheral acts differently than if they had all happened in order within some timeframe (an stm doesnt in any way insure that the far side gets things in any deterministic time frame even if not interrupted).

Comment: People may care (or at least think it matters) for latency reasons.  It depends on the CORE.  Some COREs have a configuration to control the behaviour.  Ie, atomic or restartable.  Older cores were always atomic.  Generally this would only matter with a FIQ.  Other places where IRQ are masked and nesting will generally be longer unless you have very slow memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exact answer depends on the exact core that you have. For example on ARM Cortex-M4 this opeation is not atomic and is interruptible. See here - http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0439b/ch03s09s01.html

> The processor implements the Interruptible-continuable Instruction
>   field. Load multiple (LDM) operations and store multiple (STM)
>   operations are interruptible. The ICI field of the EPSR holds the
>   information required to continue the load or store multiple from the
>   point where the interrupt occurred. This means that software must not
>   use load-multiple or store-multiple instructions to access a device or
>   memory region that is read-sensitive or sensitive to repeated writes.
>   The software must not use these instructions in any case where
>   repeated reads or writes might cause inconsistent results or unwanted
>   side-effects.

You should look for the same chapter in the documentation for the ARM core you have.