# Are ldmfd and stmfd atomic?

Tags: assembly, arm, atomic

Do the ldmfd and stmfd keep atomicity if the register list is more than 2?

such as

```
stmfd sp!, {r1-r12}
ldmfd sp!, {r1-r12}
```

can this be interrupted by events?

Comment: 1. fix your title. 2. An uninterruptible instruction is not necessarily atomic in terms of memory interactions. 3. The ARM load/store multiple instructions are neither uninterruptible nor atomic. 4. A bit of your own research would have trivially led you to this on your own.

Comment: what`s the problem of the title?

Comment: Before I fixed it for you, it said "[automatic](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/automatic)" instead of "[atomic](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/atomic)".  (And was very non-grammatical.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ARM: Is "STMDB SP!, {R0-R8}" (aka PUSH {R0-R8}) an atomic operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628136/arm-is-stmdb-sp-r0-r8-aka-push-r0-r8-an-atomic-operation)

Answer (score 0):

from this picture, it seems the ldmfd process could be disrupted by event during the register restore

[image]

Comment: the arm document describes how the instruction recovers when interrupted.  which implies....it can be interrupted...so what is this SO question about?